# How to drag and drop content of one label to another label in Silverlight 5

Tags: drag-and-drop, silverlight-5.0

I have a Form in a Silverlight 5 application with the two lables (Label1 and Label2) on it. 
The content of Label1 is “This is Label1” and the content of Label2 is “This is label2”.

I need help with code that will allow me to accomplish the following:

When I drag Label1 and drop it over Label2, the content of Lable2 changes to “This is Lable1”.

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

hi please download this sample Project for Darg & Drop In SL5.0
https://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/LogOn.aspx?download=true
for more informations Call Me by :
Savadkoohi_f@yahoo.com
by